# Showing the articles in the category on the frontend - Laravel 9 - json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I've saved the categories as JSON to the database, but I can't just foreach a category on the frontend.

So, for example, I want to show all of the 1 digits in the database with foreach. How can I do it?

Controller:

```
    public function index() {
        $contents = DB::table('posts')
            ->orderByDesc('posts.created_at')
            ->join('categories', 'posts.categories', 'categories.id')
            ->whereNull('posts.deleted_at')
            ->latest('posts.created_at')->get();
        return view('frontend.index', compact('contents'));
    }
```

Foreach in Blade:

```
@foreach($contents->where('status', '1')->where('categories', \DB::table('settings')->first()->design_1)->take(6) as $posts)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="top-post-wrap top-post-wrap-4">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img style="object-fit: cover; height: 515px;" src="{{route('frontend.cdn', $posts->img_512)}}" alt="img">
                <a class="tag top-right tag-red" href="{{route('frontend.category', $posts->slugname)}}">{{$posts->name}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="top-post-details">
                <div class="meta">
                    <div class="date">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($posts->created_at)->diffForHumans()}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4><a href="{{route('frontend.single', $posts->slug)}}">{{Str::limit($posts->title,70)}}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

DB "categories" Column in "posts" table:

```
["1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]
```

I want to see all posts in category 3 with foreach. For example, there are 3 id numbers in the JSON code I gave as an example.

Comment: You can not use "->where" in blade. you need to get your data in controller . after that you can loop through them all with a custom condition

Comment: If you want to get all posts from a specific category, there must be a relation between post model and category model. after creating this relation you can simply get all of the posts with a specific category in your controller. then you can send that data to front. there you go!